# Accepted the offer but no response from Human Resources Manager

Tags: job-offer

I have been interviewd with XYZ Company, and got the offer letter. I signed and sent it back the same day evening

There were 6-8 documents which needed to be filled, signed and send. I did fill all the documents online but the one document I initially filled it hand written and later did filled it in pdf and while sending email I attached the hand written one. Immediately sent a mail stating that ignore the previously attached attachments as one of the file is not so clean so consider the attached in the next email.

Does doing this give a negative impact to human resources manager? Will they revoke the offer for this? I called them this morning and left voicemail and no response.

Comment: How long ago did you send them the documents? Resending the documents shouldn't reflect badly on you at all, and they definitely shouldn't pull back the offer over something so inconsequential.

Comment: I received the documents on friday sent them on monday evening. Does human resource managers have right to revoke offer or is it hiring manager who must make it? I emailed monday and called them this morning left a voicemail. Does that calling immediately make any negative impact. @David

Comment: Breathe Nikhil, you're panicking. So far you have not done anything that I would say warrants revoking an offer. Mailing one evening and calling the next morning for an update is an overreaction though, and if you constantly contact them it will certainly look bad. Give them a week to get back to you - 8 documents is not a small amount and they probably have a good deal of paperwork to do before anything else can happen.

Comment: Thank you David. Yea I know its an overreaction, but I didn't call for update just called and left a note saying just giving a call to check if you need anything else from me.

Answer (score 3):

> Does doing this give a negative impact to human resources manager?

Would be guessing but I don't see how this can cause such negative impact.

> Will they revoke the offer for this?

**I seriously doubt it.**

You already went through all the interview process and were successfully accepted; sending a sub-optimal document is hardly something that disqualifies someone for a job position.

I know you are excited for this new job but don't torture yourself. At this point you are already in, so don't let this minor incident make you doubt of yourself.